How to parse Vec<u8> as Duration for Envoy ProxyWASM self.get_property ABI in Rust?
I am trying to do a POC with Proxy Rust SDK to extend envoy. I am able to parse the property Vec<u8> returned by http_context.get_property(["cluster_name"]) as utf8 string in Rust.
if let Some(prop) = self.get_property(["cluster_name"].to_vec()) {
        match str::from_utf8(&prop) {
            Ok(v) => {
                // Do something
            },
            Err(_e) => {
                // Log something
            },
        };
    }

I am having trouble parsing the request.duration attribute.
if let Some(prop:Vec<u8>) = self.get_property(["request","duration"].to_vec()) {
// How to parse this "prop" as number of milliseconds.

I tried printing out the values in vector, its [0x42, 0xf2, 0xbc, 0x13, 0, 0, 0, 0].
Any help is appreciated.
